# Что необходимо знать по javascript asp.net mvc разработчику?

Tags: jquery, ui, javascript, kendo

В проекте используются jquery и kendo ui. Знаний по самому по javascript у меня нету. Какие вещи нужно по javascript, чтобы понимать и уметь работать с jquery и kendo ui для junior developer?

Answer (score 1):

Изучите сам js хотя бы в общих чертах. Глубокого знания деталей прототипного наследования и жонглирования замыканиями от asp.net mvc разработчика обычно не требуется. А от junior'a и подавно. Впрочем только лишь чистый js вы использовать вряд ли будете, скорее всего он будет "облагорожен" какой-нибукдь библиотекой, чаще всего это JQuery. Она же, пожалуй, даже проще нативного js, поскольку в ней сознательно сглажены некоторые шероховатости чистого js и вообще создана она для вменяемого использования этого языка, поэтому в 90% случаев знание этой библиотеки будет очень полезным

Comment: Спасибо Ваш за ответ. Вот ресурс http://learn.javascript.ru, по которому я изучаю javascript. Можете подсказать, что, какие компоненты javascript входят в понятие "в общих чертах"?